# Java: Clear JFrame and load new buttons

Tags: java, swing

So, i have my main screen showing and i would like it so that when the user clicks "Login" is loads another screen. I have my second screen in another function called "fixtureLists". When i call this function it just overlays the buttons ontop of the login screen. How would i get it so that the screen is cleared and then the fixtureLists screen loads?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JFrame
{

    public Main()
    {

        loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.setBounds( 125, 300, 100, 35);
        add(loginButton);
        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //Execute when button is pressed
                fixtureList();
                System.out.println("Loading the fixtures screen");
            }

        });

    }

    public void fixtureList()
    {

        JButton editButton;
        JButton createButton;
        JCheckBox chkBox;

        setLayout(null);

        editButton = new JButton("Edit");
        editButton.setBounds( 10, 10, 100, 35);
        add(editButton);
        createButton = new JButton("Create");
        createButton.setBounds( 140, 10, 100, 35);
        add(createButton);
        editButton = new JButton("Edit");
        createButton.setBounds( 10, 30, 100, 35);



    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Main window = new Main();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(250, 430);
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(53, 56, 64));
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setTitle("PE Timetable v1.0");

    }
}
```

Comment: Oliver has your answer (1+ to his answer), but as an aside, you appear to be using a null layout and calling `setBounds(...)` on your components. While this may seem to a newbie the better way to create complex GUI's, it's a fallacy, and more you create Swing GUI's the more you learn to respect and use the layout managers and see that these creatures help immensely in creating flexible, beautiful and if need be, complex GUI's.

Answer (score 3):

I would not define the login dialog in the main frame.

Your login dialog should pop up in a dialog over the frame.

Having said that, if you want the login on the same frame, then use **Cardlayout**. On one Cardlayout have your login stuff, then when you login, switch the cardlayout to another panel.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I got rid of all the previous code and justr minimized it down to the "main(String Args[])" function, now what do i do? Sorry I'm new to JFrame

Comment: @user3255328: have you gone through the Swing Tutorials? If not, please check out the resources available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).